# Jquery Selector in Horizontal Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm Trying to build a simple horizontal accordion that will eventually contain more complex data (iframes)... The problem is that I want the size of each accordion tab to be specific to the data it contains, so I'm trying to edit what's already out there (Some tabs are larger than others).  When a user hovers over any tab I want to expand that tab to 50% (regardless of its previous size). All that is working fine, but the problem is I can't figure out how to go back to the tabs ORIGINAL width after mouseout. Right now I have the panels shrinking to 10% to illustrate the problem. If you cycle through the page then reload you will see what i mean. Any ideas?

http://www.brianvargo.com/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the original width somewhere. This is one way (with your code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $("ul li").mouseover(function(){
        if (this.originalWidth == undefined) this.originalWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'50%'},{queue:false, duration:500,}) 
    });  

    $("ul li").mouseout(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({width: this.originalWidth},{queue:false, duration:600})  
    });  
});
```

Untested, and you might choose a different way to save it, but the general idea is there.

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks. I was having trouble passing a variable for the origional width from one function to the other, but this works perfectly! Only other question I'm trying to figure out why the last few blocks keep jumping around vertically... any ideas?

Comment: Not rightly sure, but I'd be interested to hear it when you figure it out. Cheers.

Comment: I managed to get a solution by putting the ul in a div container that has a width of 200% and then cutting every other percentage in half.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in a similar situation to yours, was create an attribute with the original size on load of said element, then retrieve it for later use.